# how to insert list of data into django database?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-shell

I made a list of items in string that i wanted to insert them into my `Country` table from shell, well wasn't successful so need some help.(i tried to add it as list and tuple but didn't work just caused more errors)
I use sqlite3 database
models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    #countries list
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

a list like this
`'Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for s in your_list: Country.objects.create(country_name= s)
```